# How to select all objects that have instances of another object (has_many and has_one association)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models, User and Course.

User `has_many` Courses.
Course `has_one` User.

Right now I'm grabbing all users and displaying them on courses index page, however, I've realised that I should only be displaying users that have courses. I'm unsure how to do this?

Here is my index method from courses controller:

```
 #courses_controller.rb

 def index
    @courses = Course.all
    @users = User.all
  end
```

Here are my models:

```
# user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord   
  # User has many courses
  has_many :courses, dependent: :destroy
end

# course.rb
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user
validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

And my schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170505114247) do

  create_table "courses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "prerequisite"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.string   "picture"
    t.index ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_courses_on_user_id_and_created_at"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_courses_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  end

end
```

Comment: So are the users the instructors of the course then? You are saying there is only one user for each course.

Comment: Yes, I probably should have called user something else like instructor or coordinator. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: instead of has_one :user it should be belongs_to :user

Comment: In the course iterator on the index page include <%= course.user.name %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is a one-to-many association between users and courses then on the courses index page when you iterate over each course you can include the user information. You don't need to include @users = User.all in the controller. So your iterator might look something like this

In controller:

```
@courses = Course.includes(:user).all  #to avoid n+1 query
```

Your view:

```
# app/views/courses/index.html.erb
<% @courses.each do |course| %>
  <%= course.name %>
  <%= course.description %>
  <%= course.user.name %>
<% end %>
```